# Add p5js to Ember application

Tags: javascript, ember.js, p5.js

I'm trying to incorporate the p5js javascript library into my Ember.js app. I want the following p5js example to appear on the template:

https://p5js.org/examples/sound-record-save-audio.html

I've included the cdn script in my index.html file:

I dont know how/where in the Ember run loop to put the javascript so it runs and loads when the page loads

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest making a component, putting the component in whatever template you're rendering (could be `application.hbs` if you only have one page) and putting the Javascript into the component's `didInsertElement` method.

Along with that, I would place the p5 canvas inside your component's own Element, so that the component behaves normally (it's weird for a component to render things outside its own Element, and you'd want them to be cleaned up properly if you navigate away to some other template). The [p5 docs say how to position the canvas](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Positioning-your-canvas#relocating-the-canvas).

In your component it would look like:

```
export default Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
   createCanvas(400,400);
   canvas.parent(this.element);
   background(200);
   fill(0);
   text('Enable mic and click the mouse to begin recording', 20, 20);
   ...etc...  
  }
})
```

```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer applies for Ember app versions 1.13 onward and was written as of 3.x. Versions of Ember < 3.x will need to use the older import syntax in the component boilerplate.*

The most common place for code that should run after a page loads is the didInsertElement hook:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    console.log(p5) // this should print a function to the console
  }
});
```

Also check out didRender, which might be a better fit for your use case.

You can read more about the uses of different component lifecycle hooks in [The Guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/#toc_integrating-with-third-party-libraries-with-code-didinsertelement-code)